# What does constant binding in switch statements actually do?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, constants

It's not really clear to me how `let` is used in `switch` statements.

Consider this:

```
let greeting = (1,10)

switch greeting {

    case let (x,y) where x == y:
        print("hello")

    case (x,y) where x < y: //error here
        print("what's up")

    default: "No match"
}
```

According to the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html):

> [...] patterns in a case can also bind constants using the let keyword (they can also bind variables using the var keyword). These constants (or variables) can then be referenced in a corresponding where clause and throughout the rest of the code within the scope of the case. That said, if the case contains multiple patterns that match the control expression, none of those patterns can contain constant or variable bindings.

What is the tuple `(x, y)` bound to my example, and why can't it be referenced again?

Comment: the key is in your ref.   .. ***within the scope*** of the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your quote from the Swift documentation:

> ... can then be referenced in a corresponding where clause and throughout
>   the rest of the code **within the scope of the case.**

So in the first case

```
case let (x,y) where x == y:
    print("hello")
```

`greeting` (which is the tuple `(1, 10)`) is matched against the
pattern

```
let (x,y) where x == y
```

and if it matches, `x` is bound to the first tuple element
and `y` to the second.

This binding is restricted to the scope of the first case,
and cannot be used in the second or other cases.

To make your code compile, add another `let` binding for the second
case:

```
switch greeting {

case let (x,y) where x == y:
    print("\(x) is equal to \(y)")

case let (x,y) where x < y:
    print("\(x) is less than \(y)")

default:
    print("No match")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the original question in addition to pointing out my error. Not everyone does that...